# Move files to different directories based on file name tokens

Tags: linux, bash, automation, copying

I am looking to write a script to move files from a directory:

/home/mydir/

To another directory based on tokens in the file name. I have a bunch of files named as such:

red_office_mike_2015_montreal_546968.ext

or

$color_$location_$name_$year_$city_$numbers.extension (files will be various movie files: mov, mp4, mkv, etc.)

I would like the script to move the files to the following location:

/dir/work/$color/$name

Then verify the file has successfully copied, and delete the original file once it has.

I would also love it if the script would create the to directory if it does not already exist.

So in summary, I need a script to move files based on underscore separated tokens, create the to directory if it doesn't already exist, verify the successful copy (maybe with a size check), then delete the original file.

I am working on linux, and would prefer a bash script. The variables I have given are generic, and I will incorporate some other things to the script, I'm just looking for help on building the skeleton.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you're looking for a way to tokenize your string, use `read` with a custom `IFS`: `IFS='_.' read -r color location name year city numbers ext <<< red_office_mike_2015_montreal_546968.ext`. If you're asking to have the script written for you, wrong place dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bash script, but perl is much better at this kind of thing and is installed on all Linux systems

```
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    $file = $_;
    ($colour, $location, $name, $year, $city, $numbers) = split(/_/,$file);
    $dest0 = "/dir/work/$colour";
    $dest1 = "$dest0/$name";
    mkdir ($dest0) unless (-d $dest0);
    mkdir ($dest1) unless (-d $dest1);
    rename ($file, "$dest1/$file");
}
```

The script splits your input file on the underscore character, creates all the directories to the destination and then renames the file to the new filename.  Rename takes care of all the copying and deleting for you.  In fact it just changes the directory entries without any copying at all.

**UPDATE**

The above version takes its input from a file containing a list of filenames to process.  For an alternative version which processes all files in the current directory, replace the `while` line with

```
while(glob("*")) {
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I've saved the script as a .pl file, I've run chmod on it with the +x flag to make it executable, and I am CD'd into the directory containing the files.

When I run the script, it just hangs, no error messages, until I force quit it with ctrl+d.

Any ideas? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Save your filenames into a file and use the filename as a parameter to the script.

Comment: Worked perfectly after updating the `while` line. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fumble around online and come up with a for loop to do this task. I used `cut` and it made things simple. Here is what worked for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd "${1:-.}"

for f in *.*; do
    color=`echo "$f" | cut -d'_' -f1`
    name=`echo "$f" | cut -d'_' -f3`
    todir="/dir/work/$color/$name"
    mkdir -p "$todir"
    mv "$f" "$todir"
done
```

This worked perfectly and I hope it can help others who might need to create directories based on portions of filenames.

The first line under the shebang made it so that it will either look at the current working directory or a directory you pass it as an argument.

Thanks to those who chimed in on the original post. I'm new with scripting so it take me a while to figure this stuff out. I love this site though, it is super helpful!